# Ubuntu detects speakers wrong

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones, speakers

My laptop has 2 pairs of speakers. Ubuntu 21.10 detects them as "Speakers" and "Headphones". [AlsaMixer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSo8m.png) 
So, if I try to change the volume in the system, it changes only the "Speakers" volume. It means that only the volume of one pair of speakers is being changed. How I can config settings so that Ubuntu detects all speakers as "speakers" and I can change the volume of all 4 of them?

P.S: There is one output device [in the sound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJOMu.png).

Comment: Fallback solution:

1) Run command
`pactl load-module module-combine-sink`

2) Choose "simultaneous output to..." in the sound settings

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The goal is to increase or decrease the volume of all 4 speakers, and not 2 of them, as now

Comment: @TejasLotlikar what exactly do you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to enable simultaneous output in the default pulseaudio. You need to install `paprefs` package for additional pulseaudio controls. You can install it using

```
sudo apt install paprefs
```

Once installed, execute it through terminal using

```
paprefs
```

In the **preferences** window, choose **Simultaneous Output** tab.

Then check the option to **Add virtual output device**. Then add the 'Speakers' and 'Headphones' together as a device.

Kill the pulseaudio  process using `pulseaudio -k` and then restart it.

Comment: Yeah, that's works, but, maybe there is some opportunity to config the system so that it will detect all 4 speakers as the same objects (like "Speakers", and not "Speakers" and "Headphones"). I wouldn't like to simulate like 4 speakers in the laptop are the one sound system. Why do I have to do it if it's so?

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was:

1. Get card and device numbers using command `aplay -l`
2. Add the following code in the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device="hw:0,0" sink_name=MyOutput1
load-module module-alsa-sink device="hw:0,1" sink_name=MyOutput2 
load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=Speakers slaves=MyOutput1,MyOutput2
set-default-sink Speakers
```

3. Then restart PulseAudio to load the new configuration
   `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio`